# Translating Stata regression into R

Tags: r, stata, linear-regression

I am currently trying to translate Stata regression into R and here is the original code :

```
char ethnicity[omit]8
char cid[omit]3
xi: reg nationalism  i.cid ib(8).ethnicity male age religious education income rural_now rural_prev killed [pw=stdwt] if warcountry ==1, cl(cid)
```

and here is what I have so far in terms of translating it into R

```
lm(nationalism ~ cid + ethnicity +male+ age+ religious+ education+ income+ rural_now+ rural_prev+ killed, data=tab5data)
```

My question is how do I do the first portion of the Stata code ( `char ethnicity[omit]8`) because I know it is the reference group but I am unsure how to do that in R. Do I need to remove all those groups in the original dataset or do I need to run those groups in a seperate regression all together? Also what exactly does the `ib(8)` mean?

Comment: In Stata, you don't use the `xi` prefix any more. That's been true since Stata 10 or 11. You clearly have a newer version of Stata since you are using `ib().` syntax. For your Stata question, take a look at `help fvvarlist`. For your R question, take a look at `?factor`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `relevel()` in R. The code below uses a user-written command `rsource` to run R from within Stata to show the equivalence:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. saveold auto, version(12) replace
(saving in Stata 12 format, which can be read by Stata 11 or 12)
file auto.dta saved

. 
. rsource, terminator(XXX)
Assumed R program path: "/usr/local/bin/R"

Beginning of R output
>         library("foreign")
>         mydata<-read.dta("~/Desktop/auto.dta")
>         mydata$rep78 <- relevel(as.factor(mydata$rep78), ref = 4)
>         m1<-lm(price ~ rep78,data = mydata)
>         summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ rep78, data = mydata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3138.2 -1925.2 -1181.5   369.5  9476.8 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   6071.5      702.4   8.643 2.38e-12 ***
rep781       -1507.0     2221.3  -0.678    0.500    
rep782        -103.9     1266.4  -0.082    0.935    
rep783         357.7      888.5   0.403    0.689    
rep785        -158.5     1140.6  -0.139    0.890    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 2980 on 64 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.01449,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0471 
F-statistic: 0.2353 on 4 and 64 DF,  p-value: 0.9174

> 
End of R output

. 
. /* Old Way */
. char rep78[omit]4

. xi: reg price i.rep78
i.rep78           _Irep78_1-5         (naturally coded; _Irep78_4 omitted)

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 64)        =      0.24
       Model |  8360542.63         4  2090135.66   Prob > F        =    0.9174
    Residual |   568436416        64     8881819   R-squared       =    0.0145
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0471
       Total |   576796959        68  8482308.22   Root MSE        =    2980.2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   _Irep78_1 |      -1507   2221.338    -0.68   0.500    -5944.633    2930.633
   _Irep78_2 |   -103.875   1266.358    -0.08   0.935    -2633.715    2425.965
   _Irep78_3 |   357.7333   888.5353     0.40   0.689     -1417.32    2132.787
   _Irep78_5 |     -158.5   1140.558    -0.14   0.890    -2437.026    2120.026
       _cons |     6071.5   702.4489     8.64   0.000     4668.197    7474.803
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. /* Post-Stata 11 Way */
. reg price ib4.rep78

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 64)        =      0.24
       Model |  8360542.63         4  2090135.66   Prob > F        =    0.9174
    Residual |   568436416        64     8881819   R-squared       =    0.0145
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0471
       Total |   576796959        68  8482308.22   Root MSE        =    2980.2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
          1  |      -1507   2221.338    -0.68   0.500    -5944.633    2930.633
          2  |   -103.875   1266.358    -0.08   0.935    -2633.715    2425.965
          3  |   357.7333   888.5353     0.40   0.689     -1417.32    2132.787
          5  |     -158.5   1140.558    -0.14   0.890    -2437.026    2120.026
             |
       _cons |     6071.5   702.4489     8.64   0.000     4668.197    7474.803
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. fvset base 4 rep78

. reg price i.rep78

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 64)        =      0.24
       Model |  8360542.63         4  2090135.66   Prob > F        =    0.9174
    Residual |   568436416        64     8881819   R-squared       =    0.0145
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0471
       Total |   576796959        68  8482308.22   Root MSE        =    2980.2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
          1  |      -1507   2221.338    -0.68   0.500    -5944.633    2930.633
          2  |   -103.875   1266.358    -0.08   0.935    -2633.715    2425.965
          3  |   357.7333   888.5353     0.40   0.689     -1417.32    2132.787
          5  |     -158.5   1140.558    -0.14   0.890    -2437.026    2120.026
             |
       _cons |     6071.5   702.4489     8.64   0.000     4668.197    7474.803
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```